# BufferedReader return string as binary

Tags: bufferedreader

i tried to read line from a cvs file and need to process each line, parse out some of the fields. i used BufferedReader, but the string returned are in binary format, instead of returning 'http://foo.com' it returned '\u0000h\u0000t\u0000p'...it make my parse not working at all. how can i convert it back to a normal string that allows me to do regular String operation.

here is what i've tried:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
List<String> pieces;
String line;
while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
  pieces = splitter.splitToList(line);

  // further process of element in pieces
}
```

Comment: If you are on linux, can you post output of this command, `file <filename>` where <filename> is path of your file.

Comment: it output: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with very long lines, i m using Mac

Comment: I think problem is because of UTF-16 encoding. Javadoc of `FileReader` says the following, so can you try with `InputStreamReader` + `FileInputStream`.

`The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate. To specify these values yourself, construct an InputStreamReader on a FileInputStream.`